# Getting the directory of the file and send as attachment in outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have this code that gets the filenames on the selected directories.

```
Sub browsefile()
Dim file As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , True)

For i = 1 To UBound(file)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
    lRow = lRow + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("O" & lRow).Value = GetFileName(CStr(file(i)))
Next i
End Sub

Function GetFileName(filespec As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    GetFileName = fso.GetFileName(filespec)
End Function
```

Once I've selected the files, I have to put it in Column O. I have tried using `.FullName` but is not applicable in this area or maybe I've just misused it. Then later this will be send as attached file in an email in outlook.

By the way, I've got some of its code [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72305).

Any help?

Comment: Ok I got it, I just don't need to use the `GetFileName` function and its all set :) My problem now is how to attach them in outlook and serves as an attachment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to obtain the full path to the file that you have selected. Application.GetOpenFilename already returns you that and hence, there is no need to reprocess your file with GetFileName function?

Changing

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("O" & lRow).Value = GetFileName(CStr(file(i)))
```

To

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("O" & lRow).Value = CStr(file(i))
```

should work assuming i have understood your question correctly. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook include attachments with Attachments.Add

```
Private Sub browsefile_Att()

' Multiselect = False so file is not an array
' Dim file As Variant
Dim file As String

Dim lRow As Long
Dim main As Worksheet

Dim olOlk As Object
Dim olNewmail As Object

Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

' Multiselect = False so file is not an array
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , False)

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
lRow = lRow + 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("O" & lRow).Value = file

Set olOlk = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNewmail = olOlk.CreateItem(olMailItem)
olNewmail.Attachments.Add file
olNewmail.Display

ExitRoutine:
    Set olNewmail = Nothing
    Set olOlk = Nothing

End Sub
```